# How to convert list of integers to a map with frequency per bin?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Lets say I have a list of numbers:

```
val numbers = List(15, 30, 110, 140, 170, 210)
```

How can I count the number of integers per bin of a `100` in order to get:

```
Map(0 -> 2, 100 -> 3, 200 -> 1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// val items = List(1, 2, 3, 101, 330, 302)
items.groupBy(i => i/100).map { case (i, l) => (i*100, l.length) }
// Map(100 -> 1, 300 -> 2, 0 -> 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, you can use the [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by a `map` and a `reduce` step on values:

```
// val items = List(1, 2, 3, 101, 330, 302)
items.groupMapReduce(_ / 100 * 100)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
// Map(0 -> 3, 100 -> 1, 300 -> 2)
```

This:

- `group`s items by their associated "bin" (`_ / 100 * 100` e.g. `330 / 100 * 100 = 300`) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s grouped values to 1 (`_ => 1`) (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within each group (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) of what can be translated by:

```
items.groupBy(_ / 100 * 100).mapValues(_.map(_ => 1).reduce(_ + _)).toMap
```